# Компонент response для разных контроллеров

Tags: yii2

Всех приветствую!
Пишу API для сайта.
у меня есть несколько групп контроллеров

**controller->SiteController** 
и
**controller->api-v1->ReviewController**
Сейчас получаю ошибку:

> Response content must not be an array.

при обращение к ReviewController
В файл web.php добавил

```
'response' => [                 
        'format' => yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON, 
                        'charset' => 'UTF-8',               
         ],
```

теперь все контроллеры возвращают  json. 
Как прописать response только для контроллеров api/v1?

Comment: может быть прописать в метод `beforeAction`  строку `Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте в конктроллере написать так:

```
public function beforeAction($action) {

    \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сработал

Answer (score 0):

Используйте встроенную поддержку `RESTful API` - https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/rest-response-formatting

в файле `confi\web.php` описываете обрабатываемые URL-ы, например как это сделано у меня

```php
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'rules' => [
                //----- v1
                [
                    //Поиск данных о абоненте
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => 'v1/abonent',
                    'extraPatterns' => [
                        'GET search' => 'search', //ВНИМАНИЕ! при обращению к URL вида search/ (/ на конце) будет ошибка 404
                    ],
                    //'except' => ['delete', 'create', 'update'],
                    'pluralize' => false,
                ],
                [
                    //Прием оплаты
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => 'v1/payment',
                    'pluralize' => false,
                    'extraPatterns' => [
                        'GET /' => 'index',
                        'GET status/<id\d+>' => 'status',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

там же описываете поддерживаемые форматы для входящих-запросов

```php
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser', //для приема данных в API в формате JSON
                'application/xml' => 'yii\web\XmlParser',  //для приема данных в API в формате XML
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

В итоге, если Вы будете использовать встроенный `RESTful API` то в каком виде Вы пришлете запрос (заголовок `Accept: ...`) то
в таком же виде и получите ответ и явно прописывать в конфиге или контроллере формат ответа будет не нужно.